# Error while install Ruby mongoDrive on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, mongodb

I have ruby v2.0 with [railsInstaller](http://www.railsinstaller.org/en) ,windows 8.1.

Then when execute gem install mongo, get this error:

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing mongo:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

this is the full error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug seems to be reported here:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-998

Try to install `bson 3.2.3` and `mongo 2.1.0`.